# Websphere nodeagent and server1 stops everyday

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, application-server

I have a IBM WebSphere 8.5.5.13 ND on Windows 2016 standard edition with JDK 1.7 enabled. I see that, node agent and server1 (application server) are getting stopped everyday but the deployment manager is still up and running (i.e. admin console can be accessed). So, I have to start nodeagent and the associated server manually everyday. Investigation done so far

1. Checked if the windows servers are getting restarted everyday? No they are not
2. Checked nodeagent start and stop server logs but there are no entries to see, some command was issued for stopping
3. Checked application server profile (server1) logs but nothing is there.

FYI, I don't have clustering done on WAS but it is planned for the future.

I don't no where else I can look for the reason the node agent and server1 is getting stopped everyday.

Comment: Do you have any scheduled tasks on the system? Are the processes configured as Windows services and is there some scheduled stop action associated with the services?

Comment: No, node agent is not running as windows service yet. Deployment manager is running as windows service. I checked the task schedulers on windows but there are none. These are newly built windows servers.

Comment: Are any events logged in windows event log related to nodeagent process stopping?  Perhaps it is crashing or some indication that something is killing the process.

Comment: If it's a normal shutdown, it will be logged in Systemout.log.  If something's just killing the process, it won't. If it's normal, you -might- try shutting down the dmanager and leave th e nodeagent and server up.  If the shutdown ceases, it was something/someone on the dmgr.

Comment: @Besty, I looked for windows shutdown event (6006) but the server is up for about 5 days now. I will have to check for node agent logs

Comment: @Bruce, I will definitely try that today and let you know

Answer (score 0):

okay, this is what I found out. In my case I have

Dmgr01 - registered under windows service

Node agent - **not** registered under windows service

application server - *no need or never register application server if you have deployment manager*

Since my node agent was not registered under windows service, whenever I log-off or my session is killed due to in-activity, the default behavior is that, all running processes (jave.exe) associated with WebSphere will be crashed and **there will not be any trace of it**. This is why, I was unable to find the any logs.

I registered my node agent as windows service and everything worked.